# isset() does not work properly

Tags: php, pdo

Despite checking this topic on this site I cannot figure out what goes wrong: I developed a form in html and a php file to act on this form - see code below (in fact, most of this code I copied straight from the example at http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html).

The problem: when I do not fill in a required filed (username or password) the PHP code should indicate 'Please enter a valid username and password', but it seems the isset() function at the start of the code also returns TRUE even when the required field has not been filled in?? (E.e., the code indicates the following error message ''Incorrect Length for Username'')

Please your help. Thank you in advance.

The html form:
    
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    
    
    
    PHPRO Login

```
<body>

<h2>Login Here</h2> 
<form action="login_submit1.php" method="post"> 
<fieldset> <p> <label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text" id="username"
 name="username" value="" maxlength="20" /> </p>
 <p> <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="text" id="password"    
 name="password" value="" maxlength="20" /> </p> <p> <input type="submit" value="→ Login"
 /> </p> </fieldset> </form>

</body>
</html>
```

...and the relevant part of php file:

```
/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();

//! include lib after session_start()
include 'test_ecis_lib_pdo.php';

/*** check if the users is already logged in ***/
if(isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ))
{
    $message = 'Users is already logged in';
}
/*** check that both the username, password have been submitted ***/    
****if(!isset( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
{
    $message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
}
/*** check the username is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['username']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Username';
}
/*** check the password is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Password';
}
```

Comment: Did you try a manual entry for isset() before saying it is not working properly?

Comment: Check your $_POST var with `var_dump($_POST);`. As php docs state `isset()`, 
"Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise."

Answer (score 0):

All these verifications make no sense. Just get rid of them and proceed with SQL query.

Like all tutorials, one you linked to is a whole rubbish. What it have to be:

```
<?php
/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();

$message = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    include 'db.php';

    $username = $_POST['phpro_username'];
    $password = sha1( $_POST['phpro_password'] );

    /*** prepare the select statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT phpro_user_id FROM phpro_users 
                WHERE phpro_username = ? AND phpro_password = ?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute(array($username, $password));

    $user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    if($user_id)
    {
        /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        header("Location: profile.php"); 
        exit;
    }
    $message = 'Incorrect login or password';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPRO Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Login Here</h2>
<p><?php echo $message; ?>
 <form action="login_submit.php" method="post">
 <fieldset>
 <p><label for="phpro_username">Username</label> 
 <input type="text" name="phpro_username" value="" maxlength="20" /> </p> 
 <p> <label for="phpro_password">Password</label> 
 <input type="text" name="phpro_password" value="" maxlength="20" /> </p> 
 <p> <input type="submit" value="→ Login" /> </p>
 </fieldset>
 </form> 
</body>
```

and `db.php`

```
<?
$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = 'mysql_username';
$mysql_password = 'mysql_password';
$mysql_dbname   = 'phpro_auth';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname";
$opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields likely have a value of an empty string.  Use the  `empty` construct: `if( empty( $_POST['username'] ) )`.  I'm not a huge fan of empty because it treats the following conditions as "empty": Undefined array index (good), empty string (good), null values (good), false values (good), and numeric zero (don't like).

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `var_dump($_POST);` statement before your tests, you'll note that your form sends empty strings for `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`.

You should probably be testing for this instead:

```
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
```

Comment: thank you all for your comments(!) - Denis' suggestion worked. Lesson learned: As a beginner there are advantages to copy code from others unless it contains errors;-)

Comment: i used the same sample code as you, and had the same issue, the writer left out one line and the example works as intended, just add `session_start();` to top of login.php page.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking a user to see if they are logged in on first check before allowing them to login with username and password wow. so if a second user tries to login with the same browser you disregard there attempt to login. also `isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] )` mean it is set but i might be empty.

once a user have setup an account you do not have to recheck user/password lengths, maybe just user if you prefer to stop database query. And there is no point checking to see if  `issset(user/pass)` in second check if you are checking lengths in the 3rd and 4th check.